# Python Object, Dict, Json, List Ask

Tags: python, object, dictionary

*Hi, I am new in here. I just cannot find any way to solve this. 
I want to handle some data.*

> r = {'status': 'ok', 'name': 'Market Price (USD)', 'unit': 'USD', 'period': 'day', 'description': 'Average USD market price across major bitcoin exchanges.', 'values': [{'x': 1521158400, 'y': 8530.402}, {'x': 1521244800, 'y': 7993.674643641666}, {'x': 1521331200, 'y': 8171.415}, {'x': 1521417600, 'y': 8412.033333333333}, {'x': 1521504000, 'y': 8986.948333333334}]}

*and just want to get the 'x'and 'y' in 'values' section.*

> r['values']

```
[{'x': 1521158400, 'y': 8530.402}, {'x': 1521244800, 'y': 7993.674643641666}, {'x': 1521331200, 'y': 8171.415}, {'x': 1521417600, 'y': 8412.033333333333}, {'x': 1521504000, 'y': 8986.948333333334}]
```

*how can i get all the 'x' value from this Dictionary?
Must i do index all the funtion like this?*

> r['values'][0]['x']

```
1521158400
```

Is there anyone who can help me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
values = r["values"]
x_values = [value["x"] for value in values]
```

Dictionary values can be accessed using `dic[key]`. Since your initial dictionary have the values you are looking for as a list of dictionaries you can access those values using `r["values"]`.

This will give you:

```
[{'x': 1521158400, 'y': 8530.402}, {'x': 1521244800, 'y': 7993.674643641666}, {'x': 1521331200, 'y': 8171.415}, {'x': 1521417600, 'y': 8412.033333333333}, {'x': 1521504000, 'y': 8986.948333333334}]
```

Then, using Python's list comprehension you can create a new list of x values only using `[value["x"] for value in values]` where it says "go through all values (each time will be a dictionary that is now referenced as `value` and from that value, extract the value based on the key `x`".

The result:

```
[1521158400, 1521244800, 1521331200, 1521417600, 1521504000]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It gives me a bunch of helpful !!

Comment: @seongcheolryu Glat that this helped. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark. This helps in general maintaining SO organized when people search for questions that are not solved. In this case, though,  the question is closed which it doesn't really matter but keep in mind this for future reference as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get values from dictionaries and lists in python. You could for instance use list comprehension to modify your data to be more accessible:

```
xs = [v['x'] for v in r['values']]
```

or you could use a for loop:

```
for coord in r['values']:
    x = coord['x']
    y = coord['y']
```

or if you want to get advanced you could:

```
for x, y in [v['x'], v['y'] for v in r['values']:
    print('X: %d, Y: %d' % (x, y))
```

Comment: Absolutely simple definition! Thx :) It works well!